# How do I make a cell in a Datatable blank instead of 0?

Tags: c#, datatable

I created a datatable of X rows and Y columns.  Then I populated certain cells with integers ranging from 1 to 10. When I set my datatable to a datagrid I noticed that by default, the cells that were not populated by me have values of "0" (zero) in the datagrid.  I would prefer they be blank instead of "0".

Does anyone know if there is a default option that I have to change to make them all blank instead of zeros?  Or, must I manually replace all zeroes with blanks?  If so, how do I do this?

```
if (datatable.Rows[x][y] == "0")
{
    datadable.Rows[x][y] = null;
}
```

For this code I get the warning: "Warning Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'"  and I'm not sure why.  I tried adding .ToString but that didn't seem to work.  I am using C#, Visual Studio Express 2010.

Comment: What is the type of that column, `String`? If you haven't specified a different type it is string by default. Then you could use `Field`:

`if(datatable.Rows[x].Field<string>(y) == "0") datadable.Rows[x].SetField(y, "");` or use a nullable type with `SetField<int?>(y, null)` in the first place.

Comment: Is it WinForms or ASP.NET? How do you populate datatable? Looks like you are trying to compare cell with string, not with integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DBNull.Value

```
datadable.Rows[x][y] = DBNull.Value;
```